# android url redirection

Tags: android, intentfilter

i have links like below .

exact url

```
 <a href="activity_a://lookup/gelismeler">gelismeler</a>den
```

in textview i enabled links using the links above i want to open the speficied activity . but,  i get

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=activity_a://lookup/gelismeler (has extras) }
```

my manifest xml contains lines below

```
 <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                        <data
                            android:host="lookup"
                            android:scheme="activity_a" />
                    </intent-filter>
```

so what is wrong here ? how can i open link redirected to myactivityname://functionname/parameters to  myactivity => function => with parameters ..

thanks in advance

edit: some changes made acc. to @CommonsWare suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Get rid of `LOOKUP`, since there is no such action.

Step #2: Add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`, as I do not link that links in a `TextView` use `BROWSABLE`.

Step #3: Keep your schemes in lowercase, as I think that's a requirement of schemes.

Comment: i did what you said step1 , step2 ok . step 3 ok , i am getting the error again

Answer (score 0):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html

this a good guide for custom intent filters ...